# Calling Function in Python file from Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So i am new to the KivyMD library so this might be pretty simple to fix, but i cant find the answer anywhere on google.

**Python Code**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Finance Fun"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('my.kv')

    def Work(self, instance):
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Kivy Code**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: panel

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "files1"
            text: "Money"
            icon: "cash-plus"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: dp(10)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                    id: work
                    text: "Work"
                    icon: "hammer-wrench"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                    on_release: root.Work()
```

So if you can see in *MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:* Im calling *on_release: root.Work()* which is the function in the python file.

The **error** that shows up is:

```
on_release: root.Work()
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute 'Work'
```

If you could help me that would be very appreciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In kv lang (what you refer to "Kivy code" in your question) `root` refers to the root widget, which is in your case a BoxLayout (first line). In your python code you define the `Work()` function for `MainApp`. You can refer to your app in kv by `app`. So your kv should look like the following:

```
 on_release: app.Work()
```

What `app` and `root` means in a kv file is described [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context).